# Playframework inserting wrong date in database

Tags: java, date, timestamp, playframework

I'm having a strage problem. In my form I'm using the jQuery datetime picker. This generates a string like `05/23/2011 07:33`.

In my java code i'm using DateFormat to create a date object out of that string:

```
    System.out.println(execute);
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = df.parse(execute);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

(`execute` is the string which contains the date).
In the console, `println()` is showing the right date. And I'm using that date object when I write an instane of a Model to the database. But once I call the `save()` function (from the model), the timestamp that is inserted in the database is completely wrong.

In this case it is: `2012-11-05 07:33:00` The time is correct, but the date is sometimes more than a year off!

Any ideas what's causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure about your date format "dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm"?
You get day/month/year but in "05/23/2011 07:33" it's month/day/year, isn't it?

Comment: @Sled: try "MM/dd/yyyy kk:mm"

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue as the jQuery date time picker was using a different formatting for the date than my Java code, and that changed the date to be saved. Check it :)

Comment: The date format are not standardised the same way in JS and Java. As you, it made me crazy and I ended with tweaking the Jquery datetimepicker for CrudSiena :)

Comment: I still wonder why??? As if people writing servers and webapps were not living in the same time and date ;)